# Cannot create executable jar from Java Swing app successfully

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have made a Java Swing application and now I want to export it as an executable `jar` file. I have created the app in `Eclipse`, and it has the following structure :

[image]

where folder `mysqlconnector` contains also a `jar` file. So first I tried following the instructions in [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse) and created `seo.jar`, but when I try to execute it from the terminal by `java -jar seo.jar` I get an error :

> Error: Could not find file connectionprops.properties

As the screenshot shows, I tried putting `connectionprops.properties` in `main` package, but the same problem remains.

Then I tried making a `manifest` file named `manifest.mf` with contents :

```
Main-Class: bin.main.MainClass   //also tried Main-Class: MainClass
```

as the structure of my project is :

```
seo --> bin --> main --> MainClass.class
```

I placed the `manifest.mf` in folder `seo` and I gave the following command in the terminal :

```
jar -cvfm seo.jar manifest.mf *
```

but again when executing it from the terminal by `java -jar seo.jar` I get an error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class bin.main.MainClass

What am I doing wrong? Should I change something in my project structure? Is there a problem that I have other `jar` files inside my project? How can I create the executable `jar` and execute it successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Manifest Main-Class attribute needs to receive the package path to your Main class. It doesn't matter what the structure of the project looks like, what matters is the fully qualified package name that you have inside the src/ folder. So in this case, main.MainClass is what you should write there.

Also, if you receive other errors when trying to read the connectionprops.properties in your program, try to open the file using

```
someObject.getClass().getResourceAsStream("connectionprops.properties")
```

Comment: I changed to `main.MainClass` as you suggested but I get the same error :/

Comment: Can you check what MainClass is set in Eclipse project properties ? If you are building via eclipse, it may be that it is ignoring the manifest you wrote and using the default one. It happened to me sometimes.

Comment: It is set to my `MainClass`.

Comment: change it there then, it may be overwriting it.

Also, straight from the horse's mouth: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

Comment: The last bit is important to remember if you are writing the Manifest yourself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137895/discussion-between-edd-and-marievi).

Answer (score 0):

`bin.main` is not a package name. You can't add this to `manifest.mf`.

You should add the package name only if you have the main class in the package. If your package is default then put only the main class.

```
Main-Class: MainClass
```

Comment: Hmmm... and what should I add so that it finds `MainClass.class`?

Comment: Also, when doing this from `Eclipse` it seems to be finding `MainClass` but then it has a problem with `connectionprops.properties`....

Comment: which one, you have @ least 2 of them on the pic

Comment: It has a problem in both cases, I added the second one as a try but the problem remains.

Comment: I also tried `Main-Class: MainClass` but it gives the same error :/